# 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' when importing Lit-HTML

Tags: javascript, lit-html

I am trying to import Lit-HTML but I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I used npm to install this library ( version: 6.14.6 )

My index.js ( I have only one javascript file ):

```
import {render, html, svg} from 'lit-html';

const tasksElement = document.querySelector("#tasks");

const titleInput = document.querySelector("#title");
const descriptionInput = document.querySelector("#description");
const priorityInput = document.querySelector("#priority");
const dateInput = document.querySelector("#date");
const timeInput = document.querySelector("#time");
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
```

My package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "timemanagement",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lit-html": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The error I get: `index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Are you importing `index.js` as a module (`<script type="module" src="index.js">`)?

Comment: I import it as <script src="index.js">

Comment: That's the problem: es modules must be imported with `<script type="module" src="...">` tags, otherwise they're interpreted as normal scripts